# sudo vs "rwx" access

Tags: sudo

I would like to know if `rwx` access on Linux file system can substitute `sudo` access to run a command.

i.e.: I have the command `abcd` in `/etc/init.d/` and I do have `rwx` access for `/etc/init.d/` directory and its contents. Do I need have `sudo` access to execute the command `abcd` (`user@server:/>sudo abcd`) or I can type only `user@server:/>abcd` at the command prompt?

Comment: Just because you have permission to execute a file, doesn't mean you will have permission to do what the script does.

Answer (score 4):

Running `abcd` directly and via `sudo` are completely different things (assuming you're not `root` to begin with).

The permissions on the file will allow you to execute it *as yourself*, i.e. without extended privileges.
Running that program via `sudo` will run it *with root privileges*.

Whether running it directly will actually do what you want depends on the program. But keep in mind that generally, the result will not be the same at all.

Comment: I got it. Running as myself (without privileges) I can get error if the command calls for any data or other command outside the main folder. Correct?

Comment: You'll get problems whenever the command you started needs to access resources (of any type) that you user can't.

Comment: One lest question:
May I inform all syntaxes available to cofigure SUDO or it doesn't matter running commands through SUDO?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Running things with `sudo` should be done _only_ when they require to be run as root. `sudo` access must be limited as much as possible for normal users.